# Check in ksh if a directory is empty

Tags: directory, ksh

How do I check if a directory is empty or not in ksh on AIX?

If files exist I need to remove files only.

Comment: If you are about to remove the directory if it is empty, the easiest check is to run `rmdir` anyway.  If you want to know if there are (no) files to process, use a glob and be prepared to deal with a non-existent file name such as `*`. Bash has a way (`shopt -s nullglob`) to have a glob expand to empty/nothing when no files match; maybe `ksh` does too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a POSIX-compliant way of testing whether `dir` is empty using only built-in shell constructs. The `set` command sets the positional arguments to dot files (including the always-existing `.` and `..`) followed by non-dot files. If the directory is empty then the `.*` glob only matches `.` and `..`, and the `*` glob matches nothing so remains unexpanded.

```
set dir/.* dir/*
[ "$1" = "dir/." ] && [ "$2" = "dir/.." ] && ! [ -e "$3" ] && ! [ -L "$3" ]
```

This works on ATT ksh but fails with some shells that omit the `.` and `..` entries. To be more portable, you need to also allow for `.*` to match nothing.

```
set dir/.* dir/*
case $# in
  0) true;; # can't happen in a standard shell, this is for shells with nullglob
  2) { [ "$1" = "dir/.*" ] && [ "$2" = "dir/*" ] && ! [ -e "$1" ] && ! [ -L "$1" ] && ! [ -e "$2" ] && ! [ -L "$2" ]; } ||
     { [ "$1" = "dir/." ] && [ "$2" = "dir/.." ]; };;
  3) [ "$1" = "dir/." ] && [ "$2" = "dir/.." ] && ! [ -e "$3" ] && ! [ -L "$3" ];;
  *) false;;
esac
```

Recent enough versions of ksh allow a simpler test, but I think AIX's is too old (even its `ksh93`). Here's how you can test whether `dir` is empty in a recent enough ksh93:

```
FIGNORE='.?(.)'; set -- ~(N)dir/*; [[ $# -eq 0 ]]
```

or alternatively

```
FIGNORE=; set -- dir/*; [[ $# -eq 2 ]]
```

An alternative approach is to call `find`. This is simpler in that `find` doesn't treat dot files specially and doesn't have anything like the shell's difficulty to distinguish between a pattern that matches a single file and a pattern that is left unexpanded because it matches nothing.

```
[ -z "$(find dir/. -name . -o -print | head -n 1)" ]
```

Comment: @mikeserv The pattern `.*` must match `.` and `..` as per POSIX (annoying though it may be when writing scripts). That's assuming the entries exist, but they exist in all unices that I've ever seen (and if they do it's not up to an individual shell to decide to hide them, but up to `readdir` to return them or not). I'm surprised that posh and mksh don't comply. ATT ksh (the only one on AIX) does.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware their behavior is contrary to the standard - I suspect it is actually just a lazy mode of attempting to conform, though - *don't glob leading dots*, basically. Your `case` fixes that - but only added to the complexity. How come? Do you think I've got the wrong idea by comparing one portion of a glob match against another across `/` barriers? It works in all of my tests for all of the shells - but if I'm missing something I'd like to know. I actually just did some research on the history of that *lazy glob* thing [yesterday](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184126/52934), though.

Answer (score 0):

In any shell `[ "$(find path_to_dir -mindepth 1)" ] || echo EMPTY`

Comment: AIX find doesn't have -mindepth.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `find path_to_dir ! -name dir` or `find path_to_dir ! -path 'path_to_dir'` ?

Comment: `find path_to_dir/. ! -name .`. `-path` is a recent POSIX addition, [doesn't seem to have made its way to AIX yet](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/find.htm?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

I know of no direct way, and it also depends on whether you want also dot-files to be considered. This (or a variant thereof) may do what you want...

```
set directory/*
[[ -f $1 ]] || print empty
```

Comment: This wrongly prints `empty` if there is a broken symbolic called `*` (in addition to dot files).

Comment: @Gilles, it also prints empty if the first file expanded from that * is not regular (directory, fifo, socket...)

Comment: Yes. As said, depending on the requirements that needs adjustments. For the directory case you can extend it to [[ -f $1 ]] || [[ -d $1 ]] || print empty and similar for other special file cases. Handling dot files is a bit bulky.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the globs resolve themselves. As far as I'm aware, this strategy should be very shell portable for every case *except* one in which you have read permissions for `dir/` but only search permissions for `dir/../`. This is because read and search permissions are required to resolve a glob, but only search permissions to show up a match.

```sh
set di[r]/* di[r]/.[!.]* di[r]/..?*
case $* in 
(*r/*) echo dir not empty;;
(*]/*) echo dir is empty ;;
esac
```

This works because if a pathname resolves for any of the three globs - which do not match `dir/.` or `dir/..` - then the di[r] glob must also resolve, but the results cannot expand a `/`. The above should work for any of `posh`, `ksh`, `bash`, `dash`, `mksh`, `yash`, `mksh`, or `busybox ash`. It will also work for `zsh` if `emulate sh` is set. The following also works for the majority of those - all excepting `posh` and `mksh` as far as I'm aware - and *should* work for all POSIX shells:

For the current directory you can do:

```sh
set "/./${PWD##*/}/"
set "$1" .?"$1"* .?"$1".[!.]* .?"$1"..?*
case $* in (*.././*) set "$1";;esac
printf "%s%${2+.}3sempty\n" "${1#/} " "is not "
```

...which doesn't have the read/search permission problem because all globs resolve for the current directory - though they recurse. Here it is again, fleshed out a little:

```sh
ksh -x <<\SCRIPT  
dirempty(){
    cd -P -- "${1-.}" && set "/./${PWD##*/}/" || return 2
    set .?"$1"* .?"$1".[!.]* .?"$1"..?*
    case $* in (*.././*) set --;;esac
    printf "%s%${1+.}2s empty\n" "$PWD " "is not"
    cd -- "$OLDPWD" && return "$((!$#))"
}

###TEST LOOP###

    mkdir empty
    for new in "" ... notdot
    do  for c in touch mkdir
        do  "$c" "empty/$new" 2>&3
            dirempty empty ||
            rm -rf "empty/$new"
        done 
    done 3>/dev/null

###END
SCRIPT
```

Here's some of the `set -x` output:

```sh
+ touch empty/
+ dirempty empty
+ cd -P -- empty
+ set /./empty/
+ set '.?/./empty/*' '.?/./empty/.[!.]*' '.?/./empty/..?*'
+ printf '%s%.2s empty\n' '/home/mikeserv/empty/ ' 'is not'
/home/mikeserv/empty/ is empty
+ cd -- /home/mikeserv
+ return 0
```

It is the following line which demonstrates how it works best:

```sh
... '.?/./empty/*' '.?/./empty/.[!.]*' '.?/./empty/..?*' ...
```

...because, for each of `*`, `.[!.]*`, and `..?*`, the *whole* pathname is invalid, then so also is each part so *no* globs resolve - to include the leading `.?`. Compare that to this other section from the same output...

```sh
+ touch empty/...
...
+ set /./empty/
+ set '.?/./empty/*' '.?/./empty/.[!.]*' .././empty/...
+ set --
+ printf '%s%2s empty\n' '/home/mikeserv/empty/ ' 'is not'
/home/mikeserv/empty/ is not empty
+ cd -- /home/mikeserv
+ return 1
```

See...?

```sh
'.?/./empty/*' '.?/./empty/.[!.]*' .././empty/...
```

...because `..?*` resolves, then so also does `.?/./` so all that is needed is to look for one occurrence of `.././` in the shell array, and is handled like:

```sh
case $* in (*.././*)
```

And that's how you can simply check that a glob resolves *(and so also reliably check for any directory contents)* - just compare the unknown with the known.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which works on many Unixes,

on Bourne compatible shells (even prehistoric models),

and doesn't drill too deep (the filesystem, the CPU and the brain):

```
isempty() { [ -z "`find \"$1/.\" ! -name . -print -prune | head -1`" ] ; }
```

Comment: Note that those backslashes are needed for the Bourne shell or AT&T versions of ksh (where users are expected to assist the parser which otherwise would think the second quote closes the first one) but otherwise break `yash`.

Comment: Note that it fails for values of `$1` that start with `-` or newline.

Comment: Thank you for the improvment and the missing `\`` :). •• return •• The leading `return` isn't a serious problem since to pass it to anything you will have to "backslash" or "quote" it. BTW I don't know that many Unix admins who are able to play with such names and survive.

Answer (score 0):

I might have overseen something, but this should work as well and is IMHO more readable than set or find.

`-A` just exclude `.` and `..` but include other dotfiles.

`| head -n 5` is to shorten the `ls` in case of many files. You can omit it if you expect to have no or few files in the folders you are checking. **Edit** : I updated to 5 so we handled a sneeky file name beginning with newline(s).

```sh
if [ -z "$(ls -A /path/to/folder | head -n 5)" ] 
then 
    print "EMPTY"
else 
    print "NOT EMPTY"
fi
```

Checked on AIX 7.1

Comment: Or `if ls -A /path/to/folder | grep -q '^'`.

Comment: `$(ls -A /path/to/folder | head -n 1)` could be empty if the first file starts with newline characters.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas or even a name with only spaces.

Comment: No, space is OK, it's just trailing newline characters that command substitution removes.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Just a warning :`grep -q '^'` returns 0 on empty folder in Linux, and does not avoid the full ls listing if many files (which was the goal of the `head -n 1` at first)

Comment: If newline as first char in filename, you kill the test with error 0403-010, so specific case is handled :) You may set head -n 10 to prevent this without losing the benefit of the listing shortening

Comment: Then you get a problem with filenames that start with 10 newline characters ;-). I agree it's unlikely to happen with cooperative users. Still worth mentioning. The `grep -q '^'` approach doesn't have the problem and also shortens the listing (`grep -q '^'` for non-empty, sorry, should have specified)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas :grep -q does not shorten the ls because it does not send a sigpipe. It will work on every line of ls. Tried on AIX 6.1 : ls alone (with no display) is 0m5.43s , with grep is 0m7.24s, with head is 0m3.73s

Comment: it's the same as for `head`. Both `head` and `grep` will read a buffer full. `ls` will also buffer its output as it's not a tty. Both `grep` and `head` will exit after they've processed the first line, and `ls` will get a SIGPIPE if it writes again to stdout after that, but that would only happen for `ls` outputs that  are more than a few kilo-byte large. Try with `yes | grep -q '^'`. `yes` will terminate.

Comment: Also note that in any case, `ls` will not start outputting anything until it has read the full directory as it needs to sort that list.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas :`yes | grep -q '^'` will terminate on Linux, not on AIX 6.1.

Comment: OK, I stand corrected then. What about `yes | grep -l '^' > /dev/null`?